# Scroll within a swiper page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a swiper page in flutter where I have some textformfields as column children. Now when I focus on the last textfield. The textfield gets covered by keyboard. I would like to make the column scrollable so I put the column as child of singlechildscrollview. But since the page is already part of a swiper page and hence scrollable. The scroll is not working for the column. How do I go about implementing this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()` property for SingleChildScrollView. May be this will solve your problem.